# Windows, disable Internet Explorer 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Win 7 64 bit is shipped with IE 32 and IE 64 bit. I see the two versions of IE 9, 10, 11.

We have old legacy not upgradeable web apps from different suppliers, working only with IE 32 bit.

We haven't any web app demanding IE 64 bit, for our environment it is useless.
We have also other browsers installed, s we cannot change file association and/or default browser.

The users sometimes click on the "wrong" IE icon ( desktop, START mennu' ) and run IE 64 bit ... with disappointing results.

Is it possible to disable / uninstall the 64 bit version ?

Comment: How do you have multiple versions of IE installed or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer defaults to 64-bit version](http://superuser.com/questions/129841/internet-explorer-defaults-to-64-bit-version)

Comment: Ramhound, it isn't a duplicate. On the desktops we have both IE and Firefox. Our goal isn't to change file associations and/or the default browser.

Comment: There were several answers to the dulplicate that would avoid your users from running the 64-bit version of IE, for that reason, I voted it as being a duplicate